# C++/CLI: Implementing an abstract C# class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged results in C++ compiler error C3766

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++-cli, mixed-mode

I'm trying to implement an abstract C# class in C++/CLI. This abstract base class is already implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and as mentioned written in C#:

```
public abstract class BaseClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

In the C++/CLI assembly, I do have another interface that implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public interface class IAnotherNotifyPropertyChangedClass : public INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Now, when inheriting from the abstract C# class BaseClass and implementing IAnotherNotifyPropertyChangedClass in C++/CLI I get the following:

```
public ref class AnotherNotifyPropertyChangedClass : public BaseClass, public IAnotherNotifyPropertyChangedClass
```

This results then in following compiling error:

```
error C3766: 'AnotherNotifyPropertyChangedClass' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'void System::ComponentModel::INotifyPropertyChanged::PropertyChanged::add(System::ComponentModel::PropertyChangedEventHandler ^)'
```

As soon as I remove the INotifyPropertyChanged from IAnotherNotifyPropertyChangedClass interface declaration, everything compiles fine. Why is that? This declaration would compile fine when using C#. I'm using VS 2012 and compile a .NET 3.5 mixed mode assembly.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Edit:
Similar problem (w/o C#) here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/3047b8d1-348c-4ca6-b3f3-c396c03fedf7/
So is this behavior in C++/CLI by design?!

Answer (score 3):

This is not normal and I don't get a repro for this.  The question doesn't show actual code, I'll show mine:

The C# test class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ClassLibrary8 {
    public abstract class CFoo : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

The C++/CLI test code, after having a reference added to the C# project:

```
using namespace System::ComponentModel;

public interface class IBar : public INotifyPropertyChanged {
};

public ref class Baz : ClassLibrary8::CFoo, IBar {
    // fine
};
```

Comment: That's exactly how I've implemented the classes. The only difference is that CFoo takes a type parameter and reads "CFoo<T>". When doing the C++/CLI code in pure C# everything works as expected. Are you using VS2012 and 3.5 too?

Comment: I could try to repro that again.  But that would likely be just an enormous waste of my time again when there's yet another detail you didn't mention.  You *must* post an [SSCCE snippet](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem to get help.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is have an explicit implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged in your C++/CLI class. You can have it call to the already-implemented C# version.

I'm not 100% sure in your scenario, you may have to explicitly implement `AnotherNotifyPropertyChangedClass::PropertyChanged` instead of `INotifyPropertyChanged::PropertyChanged`.

```
private:
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler^ DuplicatePropertyChanged
    {
        virtual void add (PropertyChangedEventHandler^ value) sealed = 
            INotifyPropertyChanged::PropertyChanged::add
        {
            // Add to the event defined in the C# class.
            this->PropertyChanged += value;
        }

        virtual void remove (PropertyChangedEventHandler^ value) sealed = 
            INotifyPropertyChanged::PropertyChanged::remove
        {
            // Remove from the event defined in the C# class.
            this->PropertyChanged -= value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see your point. This is just doing what the compiler wants me to do, but why is this not neccessary when implementing the C++/CLI class in C#?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the interafce needs a implementation like:

```
#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
#endregion
```

Because the C# class is abstract it does not (have to) take care of that, and you need to implement it in your C++ class. That is the first class that is not abstract.

Comment: The abstract class written in C# IS implementing the interface. Doing the same scenario in pure C# (declaring another interface inheriting INotifyPropertyChanged and implementing it on top of the base class) works like a charm...

Comment: What I tried to say if that there are two implementations of INotifyPropertyChanged. That is a similar situation as with the public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() and IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() where you need to have both available.